# Open JInternalFrame with JDateChooser in it

Tags: java, jinternalframe, jdatechooser

My `JFrame` doesn't open `JInternalFrame` when I use `JDateChooser` in it.

The program runs in Netbeans but when I create a JAR file and copy that JAR file on desktop so program is running but it can't open `JInternalFrame`.

Comment: Please be more specific. How do you create a jar file? How do you run it? Do you see any error messages? As I understand it works ok in one case and not the other, please post the screenshots of both cases too

Comment: i create a jar file by clean and run . no there is no error msg

Comment: when i compile and run the application it works perfectly but when i create jar file it works in dist folder only but when i copy it to any other folder or desktop it was not opening a internal frame . And one more thing when i remove Jdatechooser from my internal frame and then i create jar file and paste where ever i want then my application was opening an internal frame

Comment: Please attach screenshots for all of that

Comment: Thank You Ivan For your Corporation the problem is solved :)

Comment: Awesome. Would you like to share the solution with the rest of the world and accept it thus closing the question?

Comment: Yeh Sure I Love to